# Django template translation: zero is plural in fr

Tags: django, translation

I am using Django and cannot get the correct plural form in my template using French, whatever text I use in my blocktrans tag. For example:

```
{% blocktrans count counter=0 %}
    foo
{% plural %}
    bars
{% endblocktrans %}
```

Gives me `bars` instead of `foo`. Indeed, 0 is singular in French.

I checked the language code with the following in my template:

```
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}
```

It gives me `fr`.

The following is in the header of my `django.po`file for French translation:

```
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n > 1);\n"
```

Do you have any idea guys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I finally found what is going on here. Because of the way I typed the `blocktrans`, here is what I got in the `django.po` file generated by the `python manage.py makemessages -l fr` command:

```
msgid ""
"\n"
"                                foo\n"
"                            "
msgid_plural ""
"\n"
"                                bars\n"
"                            "
msgstr[0] ""
msgstr[1] ""
```

And I put something like that as `msgstr[0]` and `msgstr[1]`:

```
msgstr[0] ""
"\n"
"                                foo\n"
"                            "
msgstr[1] ""
"\n"
"                                bars\n"
"                            "
```

So I updated the template from:

```
{% blocktrans count counter=0 %}
    foo
{% plural %}
    bars
{% endblocktrans %}
```

To:

```
{% blocktrans count counter=0 %}foo{% plural %}bars{% endblocktrans %}
```

With the following translation:

```
msgid "foo"
msgid_plural "bars"
msgstr[0] "foo"
msgstr[1] "bars"
```

It looks like if there is something wrong (the translation strings is missing or empty) in your `django.po` then it results in a bad 0 interpretation in template.

I'll leave it there... Hope this helps!

Comment: I also found that if you do not translate your blocktrans and test in FR (or other languages), 0 (zero) display the plural. Once translated, everything went fine :-)